# Android Incorrect value when converting String to StringEntity

Tags: android, string, http-post, json

I am sending a string to server using HttpPost.
This string is a JSONObject thath i have previously converted to String
So far everything is working properly...
It must be sent with content-type "application / json".

To send it, convert my String to a StringEntity and add to httpPost.setEntity (my_string) ... The problem is that the server tells me that does not recognize the data (is ready to receive the JSONObject converted to String)

In my code, I use a log to know the value of the String before converting to StringEntity, and this is the result:

```
String: {"Gender":"male","User":"Pedro","Email":"ejemplo@ejemplo.com","Language":"English"}
```

However, when I convert this String to StringEntity, the result of the Log, instead of being the same, it is as follows:

```
String: org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@16a4bc74
```

Why?

I do not know what I'm doing wrong ...

I searched and I found many examples, I think I'm doing it correctly ... I do not understand the error.
Why the string, when converted to StringEntity not maintained values?

I have tried many examples, such as http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/, and many more.

This is my code.

I appreciate the help very much.

Greetings.

public static JSONObject makeServiceCall(String url, JSONObject params) {

```
try {

    Log.i("dmode", "LLegan los valores:" + " " + params);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


    if (params != null) {

        String conversion = params.toString();

        Log.i("dmode", "JSONBoject to String" + " " + conversion);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(conversion);

        Log.e("dmode", "String to StringEntity" + " " + se);

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

    }

    String response = null;

    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Log.i("dmode", "Devolución" + jObject);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return jObject;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using URL Connection :

```
public JSONObject readJSONFromURL(String urlString, JSONObject param){
        String response = null;
        JSONObject jObject = null;
        try {           
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dmode", param.toString()));
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = getStringFromInputStream(in);
            jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "UnsupportedEncodingException " + e.toString());
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "IOException " + e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "JsonException: " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObject;
    }

    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) { 
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This can be a good solution @abhishesh , but as I can apply the Content-type "application / json "? conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); not work

Comment: you dont need to apply content type